# Magento Configurable Product Overwrite Defaults by URL

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, configurable-product

I was browsing through `js/varien/configurable.js` and noticed a comment that said, `// Overwrite defaults by url`.  Does mean there is a way to pre-select the drop down values by altering the url?

If so, can you please show me an example of how this is accomplished (example: color)?  Perhaps `http://www.example.com/test/product.html#color=blue`?  What are the options for the url to modify the selections?  Associated sku? Attribute and option labels? Attribute and option IDs?

```
    // Overwrite defaults by url
    var separatorIndex = window.location.href.indexOf('#');
    if (separatorIndex != -1) {
        var paramsStr = window.location.href.substr(separatorIndex+1);
        var urlValues = paramsStr.toQueryParams();
        if (!this.values) {
            this.values = {};
        }
        for (var i in urlValues) {
            this.values[i] = urlValues[i];
        }
    }

    // Overwrite defaults by inputs values if needed
    if (config.inputsInitialized) {
        this.values = {};
        this.settings.each(function(element) {
            if (element.value) {
                var attributeId = element.id.replace(/[a-z]*/, '');
                this.values[attributeId] = element.value;
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that you can pre-select product attribute options using the url, however, it is not a very user-friendly way of doing so.  The full url must be followed by `#attribute_id=option_id`.  You'll want to have access to the database to get the appropriate ids unless you have plans of using native Magento functions to implement this.

**Example**

> http://www.example.com/test/product.html#107=54&33=82

When you load this url, Magento will pre-select those values from the dropdown menus.  Believe me, I would rather it be something like this: `#attribute_code=option_code (#color=dark_blue)`, although I am *almost* certain that there are only ids and labels for options of a drop down.

If you're looking for a way to make this more user-friendly, perhaps try adding `url rewrites` to accomplish this.  Example: `http://www.example.com/test/product.html#107=54&33=82` to `http://www.example.com/test/dark-blue-product.html`